# Run iOS code every minute comparable to android service

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10

I have an android app that runs a service every minute checks a server and it works great. I am new to iOS and don't see a comparable solution and wanted to get what the best practice would be or if this is possible. I have the code written in swift 3 and it is working on a timer. It does work correctly but I feel my app will be killed at some point

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a push notification for this?

Comment: what do you mean? i am using a local notification if the server has new data to alert the user but what would a push notification do? like send one from a remote server to the device?

Comment: Exactly, there is absolutely no reason to start the app every minute, instead an event driven approach would be preferable where the server determines whether or not there is new data and notifies the device if so.

Comment: What's the best way to implement remote push notifications from your experience? Any advice?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial looks good (even though still ins Swift 2.2) and https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1 for a general overview.

Comment: I ended up making node.js app and did the remote notifications. thanks for all the help

Comment: Perfect! Glad I was of help :)